# How to manually serve a laravel project on filemaker server

Tags: php, html, laravel, apache, filemaker

I have Filemaker server 19 running on ubuntu 18.04,it allow me to host a web page, because it include apache inside, is there any way to load a laravel project on it?
Which file start a laravel project to call it on apache start?

Here is part of httpd.conf code file

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/opt/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/HTTPServer/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory> 
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes to your laravel project

1. On your project root "server.php" rename to "index.php".
2. Copy ".htaccess" from public to root directory.

Now project will run without the 'PHP artisan serve' command.

Comment: I already tried it after your answer, right now apache apoint to index.php but I see it like a code only, maybe my apache miss some modules to correctly read it.

Comment: Seems like your server doesn't support PHP extension or PHP is not installed on your server.